# --dbpath not working to change where to store databases in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, syntax-error

When running the command to set a new directory where to store databases it doesn't work.

This is the command I'm running:

`mongod --dbpath C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\nik_db_folder`

This is The error I get

`\uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier : @(shell):1:9`

I have also tried to enclose the file path in double quotes but it doesn't work anyway.

Can anyone help me to understand what's the error here?

Comment: Try `mongod --dbpath "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\nik_db_folder"` - required due to the space character in the path. In general you should revise to store program **data** under `C:\Program Files` which usually hold the binaries.

Comment: It looks like the command worked as no error was returned. But in the mongod.conf file the dbPath is still "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\data". Shouldn't that change?